# Fullcalendar: draggable object rejects fullcalendar as droppable even though fullcalendar accepts drop

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, draggable, droppable

I have set up FullCalendar to accept drops, which it does.  But the draggable object, which I have constructed with revert:'invalid' does not seem to recognize the dates on FullCalendar as droppable, and reverts back.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>

  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>mydrag</title>
  <script src="fullcalendar-bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><body>
<div id="mydrag" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">My Drag</div>
<div id="calendar"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function onExternalEventDrop(date, allDay) {
    alert("Dropped on " + date + " with allDay=" + allDay);
}

$('#mydrag').each(function() {

    // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
    // it doesn't need to have a start or end
    var eventObject = {
        title: 'MyDrag Title'
    };

    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
    $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        //revert: 'invalid',
        revert: function(droppableObj) {
            //if false then no socket object drop occurred.
            if(droppableObj === false) {
                //revert the .myselector object by returning true
                alert('Not a droppable object');
                return true;
            }
            else {
                //droppableObj was returned,
                //we can perform additional checks here if we like
                //alert(droppableObj.attr('id')); would work fine
                //return false so that the .myselector object does not revert
                return false;
            }
         },
        revertDuration: 500,  //  original position after the drag
        start: function(e, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).css('width', $(this).css('width'));
        }
    });

});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    aspectRatio: 2.25,
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'prev,next'
    },
    columnFormat: {
        month: 'dddd'
    },
    droppable: true,
    drop: onExternalEventDrop
});

</script>
</body></html>
```

When I drag the draggable element onto the calendar, the element reverts back (suggesting that the calendar date was not recognized as a valid droppable)....but the drop callback *is* triggered with the expected alert (suggesting that FullCalendar recognized the draggable as valid).  I would expect that the draggable should not revert back.  Am I doing or expecting something wrong?  I have searched all over, but not found anything to explain this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Forgot to mention, what I have called "fullcalendar-bundle.js" is a file containing the following:

- jquery 1.5.2
- jquery ui 1.8.11
- fullcalendar 1.5.2 plugin

Another update: I have just tried the FullCalendar 1.5.3 release, but see the same behavior.

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help you:

**working version of drag and drop** : http://jsfiddle.net/wkKfB/15/

**Solution for dragobj = false is** that you need to bind droppable event to the calendar so that **draggable** knows what DOM object is **droppable** see working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CZQkm/3/ && http://jsfiddle.net/DEsdN/12/
***Until here**

(**Your version but with some tweaks.** By the way I have jsfiddl-ed your issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/wkKfB/16/) (issue was binding the external event)

Good documentation reside here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/dropping/droppable/

Issue was you need to externally add these drag event.

You can change the css and make it to your use.

**Quote** **[From the documentation above around external drag and drop.]** http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/dropping/droppable/

```
>     How can I use this to add events???
>     
>     Good question. It is a common need to have an "external list of events" that can be dragged onto the calendar.
>     
>     While the droppable option deals with generic jQuery UI draggables and is not specifically tailored to adding events, it is possible to
> achieve this with a few lines of code. Follow the
> external-dragging.html example in FullCalendar's download. You can
> also view the example online.
>     
>     In short, you must call renderEvent yourself in the drop callback.
```

another link: http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/external-dragging.html

**To capture the external event you need to add this code but the sample above has all set for you and should be clear**

```
 /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
$('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

    // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
    // it doesn't need to have a start or end
    var eventObject = {
        title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
    };

    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
    $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });

});


/* initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
```